# Using unbuffered pipe as "dummy" file output

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, buffer, stdout

I've been dealing with a weird issue that I can't find a way to solve.

My situation is as follows.

I have an application in python called "app1", that **requires a file for outputting** the results of it's execution.

I have a secondary application, called "app2"; a binary, that gets the **input from stdin**.

I want to pipe what "app1" is generating directly into "app2" for processing, what in an ideal situation would be like this:

```
app1 | app2
```

But, as I said, there are some restrictions, like the fact that app1 **requires a file** to be the output.
The first solution I found for "fooling" app1 into outputting to stdout is to use mkfifo and create a pipe, so I can pipe it into stdin in app2. Like this:

```
pipe='/tmp/output_pipe'
mkfifo "$output_pipe"

python app1 -o "$output_pipe" &
app2 < $tmp_pipe
```

The problem is that eventually, during the execution, app1 will generate more output than what app2 can handle as an input, and **due to the buffer size restrictions on the pipe**, the pipe will fill up and everything will stop working.

Then I used this other approach:

```
python app1 -o /dev/stdout | app2
```

But the situation is the same as stdout has buffer size restrictions too.

Anyone has any idea on how can I solve this specific scenario?

***TL;DR: I need a "dummy" file that will act as stdout but without the standard size restrictions of the pipes.***

Comment: It sounds like you have a deadlock issue that needs to be resolved.  Creating an larger pipe is not going to be the best solution.

Comment: In particular, the statement "the pipe will fill up and everything will stop working" doesn't make much sense.  If the pipe fills up, then app1 will block on a write, but app2 should continue working.  When it clears data from the pipe, app1 will start writing more data.  Unless you have some other deadlock you're not describing.

Comment: My deduction was because if I try to use a buffered pipe, after a couple of hours running, the app2 will stop working.

If I use an unbuffered pipe, like stderr, the application keeps running for hours without problem. That was the only reason for my (maybe wrong) deduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. My bad.

It was not a buffer problem, as some people suggested here.

It was a CPU cap problem. Both applications were consuming 100% for the CPU and RAM when running and that's why the application crashed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several utils designed to handle similar situations:

1. `buffer`: `python app1 -o /dev/stdout | buffer | app2`
2. `stdbuf`: `python app1 -o /dev/stdout | stdbuf app2`
3. `unbuffer`: `python app1 -o /dev/stdout | unbuffer app2`
4. `mbuffer` (`buffer` with more options): `python app1 -o /dev/stdout | mbuffer | app2`
5. [`bash` *process substitution*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):  `python app1 -o >(app2)`

The utils have various options, some of which may be required here, (that depends on what *app1* and *app2* are doing).  Some options set the size of the buffer, or add delays, or show diagnostic info.

[*Pixelbeat.org* has some diagrams](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) to help visualize how buffering works, (or fails to).

Comment: Plus there's a [`socat` trick here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252418/165517), but I'm not quite sure what it does...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Use a file. Instead of reading from stdin have the consumer read from a file and implement the file following code from "tail -f"
2. Write a pipe buffer program. This option is kind of silly but works if you cannot change either of the others. I wrote one in Perl a while ago, sorry can't share it, but basically use non-blocking IO to read from a pipe and write to a pipe, holding all the data in memory. Probably good to log a complaint if memory use goes too high.
3. Modify the reader or writer to use non-blocking IO and buffer the output or input.